# Dependence: Direction Vectors & Distance Vectors

Tags: dependencies, code-analysis

Topic: Dependencies (True, Anti, Output)

How does one get the **direction vector** and the **distance vector**?

For example:

```
do n = 3, 100
  v(n) = v(n-1) + v(i+1) + v(i-2)
end
```

Determine the dependency. Show how to calculate direction vector and distance vector.

I'd also appreciate any material that makes this easy to understand (as far as finding the direction and distance vectors).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer of your question is somehow not easy. Direction vectors and dependence vectors these are very broad concepts specially used in computer architecture and "Parallel and Optimized compiler construction".
I'm suggesting you that go through these two pdfs, they will not waste your time.

Here is link..

Visit [https://engineering.purdue.edu/~milind/ece573/2011spring/lecture-14.pdf](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Emilind/ece573/2011spring/lecture-14.pdf)

Also refer [http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~mstrout/CS553/slides/lecture18b.pdf](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/%7Emstrout/CS553/slides/lecture18b.pdf)
(This original colostate.edu link is dead, here is internet archive link)

[https://web.archive.org/web/20100618165353/https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~mstrout/CS553/slides/lecture18b.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20100618165353/https://www.cs.colostate.edu/%7Emstrout/CS553/slides/lecture18b.pdf)

Hope it help !!

Courtesy :
colostate.edu and purdue.edu